# Change login screens with Flat-Remix shell theme on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, desktop-background, css

I'm on 18.04 installed 18.04 on a Dell E4310 with a 1TB SSD, and I'm trying to change that screen, but also the first login screen after reboot.

I edited the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` (after backing it up), and

```
lockDialogGroup {
background: #2c001e url(file:///home/user/file.jpg) ...}
```

only changes the color. If I remove the color, the screen shield bugs and I still don't end up with the "file.jpg".

I don't know what to do, I tried url("file:, url(file:, url("file:///home, url("file:/home, but nothing seems to work. I tried to call the background-image property instead of the background, but it messes things up more.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105600/discussion-on-question-by-klemuntu-change-login-screens-with-flat-remix-shell-th).

Answer (score 0):

So, obviously the title changed for obvious reasons : I have Flat-Remix installed as the shell theme.

First, here is the redirections shown by ll :

```
$ ll /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 3月   1 20:30 /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css -> /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
$ ll /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51510 3月  15 13:28 /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

If other files need to know their redirections, I'd gladly know.

Since the gnome-shell.css show these lines for lockDialogGroup, I choose not to change it, and rather change the image in the assets folder.

```css
#lockDialogGroup {
    background: url("assets/login-background");
    background-size: cover; }
```

After a reboot, nothing has changed, two reboots, nothing : the colour I set in ubuntu.css still takes on both the login and the unlock screen.

Hence I decided to comment the lockDialogGroup line in the ubuntu.css file.

The result is a still only colored login screen (color #FDF030) and a bugging black/shield_screen for the unlock screen.

I checked the pages mentioned int he commentaries above, but none helped.